# AVAudioPlayer being interrupted by MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, avaudioplayer

I am writing an app that uses both `AVAudioPlayer` to play local mp3 files and `MPMusicPlayerController` to play system / Apple music / iTunes music.
I am maintaining a custom `nowPlayingMP3Item` that is being set after I play the song using `AVAudioPlayer`.

I could check the playback state of the MusicController, but I'd need to reload the UI if it changed from mp3 to system music...

Is there any way to observe (maybe the audio session) or something and determine whether mp3 or system music is playing and update the UI accordingly?

Thanks for any help

Comment: Did you try listening to `AVAudioSessionInterruptionNotification` notifications?

Comment: yep, just tried it. works great :) thanks

Answer (score 0):

When there is an interruption,the audio will be paused and your audio session will been deactivated. If your app contains playing interface, you will need to update the interface. When the interruption ends, you can activate audio session and resume playback of the audio.

```
NotificationCenter.default.addObserver( forName: .AVAudioSessionInterruption, object: nil, queue: nil) { n in
    let why = AVAudioSessionInterruptionType( rawValue: n.userInfo![ AVAudioSessionInterruptionTypeKey] as! UInt)!
    if why = = .began {
        // began
    }
    else {
        // ended
    }
}
```